# Express $S$ in set notation and determine whether it's a subspace of the given vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V = R^{n}$, and $S$ is the set of all solutions to the non-homogeneous linear system $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a fixed $m × n$ matrix and $b(≠0)$ is a fixed vector.

Express $S$ in set notation and determine  whether it's a subspace of the given vector space $V$.

-I am brand new to set notation and not sure where to go with this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $S = \{x \in V \mid \text{blah-blah-is-true-of}(A, x, b)\}$

Comment: How would I test for what these values are true of?

Comment: First of all, what is "blah-blah-is-true-of(A,x,b)"? Sometimes you can, sometimes you cannot – depends on what the condition expresses. Consider $X = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \text{the Riemann hypothesis is true} \}$: it's equal to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\emptyset$ but if you can figure out which then you've won a big prize. This problem is much simpler. Is $0 \in S$ ?